# Regex parsing out of @references, including with quotes?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text file which includes parts like

> Hello @David my name is @"Fred Foo" and this is a test.

"@" always indicates the start of a name, and Fred Foo is quoted as there's a space in his name. How would one, using JavaScript and regex, return a list of all the @-names, i.e. "David" and "Fred Foo"? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
var re = /@("[^"]+"|\S+)/g,
    matches = [],
    input = 'Hello @David my name is @"Fred Foo" and this is a test';
while (match = re.exec(input)) matches.push(match[1]);

console.log(matches); // [David, "Fred Foo"]
```

Comment: Terrific, thanks! I've added match[1].replace(/\"/g, '') to parse out the quotes too.